# What is the best way to get "How did we get here" achievement?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

What is the best or fastest way and how, to get this hidden achievement in minecraft java?

Answer (score 4):

## How to get "How did we get here"

This achievement is the rarest and most difficult achievement to complete. To achieve the "How Did We Get Here?" advancement, players will have to apply every status effect on themselves. It is nowhere near as easy as it sounds. Players will have to get 26 unique status effects to complete this advancement.

#### List of status effects to get "How Did We Get Here?" advancement

- Absorption
- Bad Omen
- Blindness
- Conduit Power
- Dolphin's Grace
- Fire Resistance
- Glowing
- Haste
- Hero of the Village
- Hunger
- Invisibility
- Jump Boost
- Levitation
- Mining Fatigue
- Nausea
- Night Vision
- Poison
- Regeneration
- Resistance
- Slow Falling
- Slowness
- Speed
- Strength
- Water Breathing
- Weakness
- Wither

#### Mobs needed for applying status effects

Players will have to gather the following mobs in one place as well:

- Elder Guardian for Mining Fatigue
- Dolphin for Dolphin's Grace
- Shulker for Levitation

Players will also have to get the Bad Omen effect by killing a raid captain and the Hero of the Village effect by protecting a village from a pillager raid in Minecraft.

#### Items needed for applying status effects

Lastly, players will have to get these items in order to apply other effects:

- Rotten flesh for Hunger
- Conduit and prismarine for Conduit Power
- Spectral arrow for Glowing
- Golden apple for Absorption
- Beacons for Resistance and Haste
- Wither rose for Wither
- Pufferfish for Nausea
- Suspicious stew made with Azure Bluet for Blindness

---

This post is just to show *how* to get this achievement, not the best way to do so, maybe someone could consildate sources and ideas into one answer for the best/fastest way?

---

Source:

- [Sportskeeda](https://www.sportskeeda.com/minecraft/how-obtain-how-did-we-get-here-advancement-minecraft)

---

## Fastest way to achieve this

Of course, there are many other ways to do this challenge, but I will just share how [Curcuit](https://m.youtube.com/c/Curcuit) did it.

Video link: [Curcuit speedrun 18:20 IGT | WR](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0S-9c_U7eZs)

There is no easy way to get this achievement, best is to find a good seed, and find all the locations of the required resources and jot them down. Note that Curcuit used the igenious method of throwing items down, before leaving, rejoining, then quickly restarting minecraft and rejoining to get double the items, basically duping.

Note:

- Logging out of minecraft does not contribute to your time

Comment: There are speedruns for How did we get here, so it's not hard to figure out an optimal strategy. It will be just pretty long to explain.

Comment: Hmm, but I was just wondering whether someone could collate some links and add some explanation, but if it is too long to explain, then maybe not I guess @pinckerman

Comment: No ok I was thinking about getting EVERY single advancement, this is just the hardest one. So maybe it's not too long, but still, you're asking for the "best way", and that definitely exploits glitches, weird behaviours when you change the render distance, or other obscure mechanics with the fishing rod that may need further explanations

Comment: @pinckerman in my new post below, circuit speedrunned getting the achievement, but he used a seed that he already memorised, can I still use it for explanations (as random seeds are extremely difficult to get the resources needed)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136622/discussion-between-dialfrost-and-pinckerman).

Comment: A notch apple gives you regeneration, absorbtion, resistance, and fire resistance all in one so one of those could be helpful